# plotting (5,4) pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this of shape `(5, 4)`:

```
kernel    linear      poly       rbf   sigmoid
0.001   0.030457  0.042301  0.272420  0.272420
0.010   0.013536  0.035533  0.272420  0.025381
0.100   0.008460  0.023689  0.042301  0.108291
1.000   0.005076  0.016920  0.015228  0.111675
10.000  0.003384  0.016920  0.010152  0.113367
```

I am trying to plot this data with the `C` values as the labels in the X axis and 4 lines for `poly`,`linear`,`rbf`,`sigmoid`. How can I do so?

I tried to `df.plot()` but this produced a plot that had 6 values in it's X axis instead of the 5 I want. I am not sure why there are 6 values

Attempt:

```
df_p = df.pivot(index='C', columns='kernel', values='error')
pl = df_p.plot(title='Error vs C',)
```

Comment: Please share the dataframe as a line of code which can be copied and pasted and also the code you tried. There are 6 values presumably because you seem to have 5 float numbers and 1 `C` value.

Comment: @Bazingaa updated!

Comment: Can you rewrite the dataframe in a copyable form as `df = .....`

Comment: @Bazingaa Just use `df=pd.read_clipboard()`, it is doing a great job.

Comment: What is `C` in your dataframe? The Dataframe looks strange

Comment: @Bazingaa C is the column with 0.001, 0.010, etc

Comment: Strange, I get `nan` in th first row when I read using clipboard as `0 C NaN NaN NaN NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**: The chart uses log-linear axes.

```
df.plot.line(x='kernel', y=df.columns[1:], style='-o', logx=True)
```

[image]
You can add grid, labels, and titles if you want.

Comment: I get a different plot when I just use the clipboard and your single line of code

Comment: Expecting the X axis to have 0.001, 0.010, 0.100, etc... Also how come there are 6 points when there are 5 rows? The plot you have is what I have in my experimentation too but it isn't what I am going for

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The points' X coordinates are definitely  0.001, 0.010, 0.100, etc.  And there are 5 points per curve, not six.

Comment: @Liondancer: you keep saying six points.  Are you confusing points with x-axis labels, maybe?

Comment: @Bazingaa The first row of the dataframe is captured incorrectly by `read_clipboard` because the dataframe is incorrectly formatted in the OP. Just drop it.

Comment: @DSM What I am trying to do is get the values in the `C` column (`0.001, 0.010, 0.100, 1.000, 10.000`) to be TICKs in the X axis. With the `linear` column values (`0.030457,0.013536,0.008460,0.005076,0.003384`) one line should be produced associated with each TICK in the X axis. Same would apply for `poly`, `rbf` etc, Sorry if I was unclear. I may not be stating my problem correctly

Comment: How do you expect to have tick labels at 0.001 and then at 0.01? There is simply not enough space. You can use log X scale, but then you must mention this in your question.

Comment: See the updated answer: Your data is plotted on the log-linear axes.

Comment: I would suggest you to also show the lines dropping unnecessary things when copying from clipboard. Feel free to copy from my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in df_p.columns.difference(['C']):
    plt.plot(df_p['C'], df_p[col])
```